# I need to find pairs of shows that started in the same year in prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to make a rule that finds pairs of these shows that started in the same year. Here are three examples of shows I have listed.

```
show( seinfeld   , 1989 , 8.9 ).
show( twin_peaks , 1990 , 8.9 ).
show( the_xfiles , 1993 , 8.7 ).
```

I've tried variations of

```
same_year(Year) :- show(Show,Year,Rating).
```

But the issue that I run into is that it gives me a `true` or `false` based off if the year input matches.

I need it to give me the shows that match. I feel like I'm just dumb,  but a little nudge would help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find *pairs*? You want to find

- a first match, and
- then find another match that isn't the first match, but shares the same year

right?

And then, you need to return the match in the head of your predicate:

Something like this:

```
same_year( Year, Show_1, Show_2 ) :-
  show(N1,Year,R1) ,           % find a 1st match    
  show(N2,Year,R2) ,           % find a 2nd match (with the same year)
  Show_1  = show(N1,Year,R1),  % construct show #1
  Show_2  = show(N1,Year,R2),  % construct show #2
  Show_1 \= Show_2             % and ensure that they don't unify       
  .                            % easy!
```

On backtracking it will find all possible pairs for the specified year (or all years if you don't specify a year).

Comment: If you use `N1 @< N2` , you won't see duplicates.

Comment: I think you have Year and N swapped in all `show()` uses; for clarity if not function.